# R question on variable assignment involving a date

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to combine data via a simple read from the CBOE and quantmod data from Yahoo. I am have a few problems with understanding how R works. I am reading SKEW data from the CBOE (Chicago Board of Options) via:

```
skew <- read.csv("http://www.cboe.com/publish/scheduledtask/mktdata/datahouse/Skewdailyprices.csv",skip=1,header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The first column of data is a date in mm/dd/yyyy format. Then I tried to convert this to a date:

```
skew.dte <- as.Date(skew[,1],format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

which works but, if I then do:

```
head(skew)    
      Date   SKEW    
1 1/2/1990 126.09     
2 1/3/1990 123.34    
3 1/4/1990 122.62    
4 1/5/1990 121.27    
5 1/8/1990 124.12    
6 1/9/1990 119.82
```

My question is, why is `dte` not part of the dataframe `skew`? I thought the `skew.dte` would do this.

Comment: Because in your second assignment you want a dollar sign instead of a period in `skew.dte`?  R isn't python (sadly).

Answer (score 4):

R allows points in variable names, often used in lieu of a space to separate words in the name of a variable

```
skew.dte <- as.Date(skew[,1],format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

assigns values to the variable called `skew.dte`.

If you want to add the values to the data frame use

```
skew$dte <- as.Date(skew[,1],format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk: well, you also gave another option!

Answer (score 3):

As Conjugate stated, you need to use a $ to access items within an object (here a dataframe), or the [ operator.  See the [R user manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) Chapter 6 for more

```
skew$dte <- as.Date(skew$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

or

```
skew[,'dte'] <- as.Date(skew[,'Date'],format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

(or any mixture thereof)